# Node JS и timestamp to date

Tags: timestamp, node.js

Потихоньку изучаю nodejs и столкнулся со странной проблемой.
есть timestamp: 1380816002
Хочу вывести это в нормальном виде. Для этого использую пакет moment. и вот тут возникает странное поведение, 
`moment( 1380816002 )` мне выводит Sat Jan 17 1970 03:33:25 GMT+0400, хотя должно быть Thu, 03 Oct 2013 16:00:02 GMT
ЧЯДНТ? Куда смотреть?

Comment: X * 1000 = ms

Comment: вот блин) тоже только что вспомнил про это... спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В тыщу раз ошибка, да?

```
moment.unix(timestamp);
moment(timestamp*1000);
```